# "StackApps authentication failed" on data.stackexchange

Tags: bug, status-norepro, data-explorer, oauth2

- I am currently logged-in to stackoverflow.com
- I am not logged-in to data.stackexchange.com
- I try to login using my Stack Overflow session and I get the error message "StackApps authentication failed".

[image]

Comment: Already reported on Meta Stack Exchange: [Can't login to SEDE - "StackApps authentication failed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380834/cant-login-to-sede-stackapps-authentication-failed)

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks - I tried looking for that but I didn't get any relevant search results.

Comment: For folks who may be following, this works now.

Comment: As the comments indicate, this seems to no longer be an issue. In case it re-occurs, feel free to retag with [meta-tag:status-review].